# Jira Trigger Logger location

Tags: jenkins-jira-trigger

anyone knows where are "com.ceilfors.jenkins.plugins.jiratrigger.webhook.JiraWebhook" logger location in windows machine ? where can I find the output file ?

[image: debugging logger]

Answer (score 0):

Add it as a new log recorder in https://[your-jenkins-ip]/log/
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/viewing-logs/#logs-in-jenkins